# How would I remove all text outside single quotes in VIM using regex?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I'm using a vim script to quickly edit some text. I have a large list from an api endpoint that looks like this:

```
                save:   presets.api + 'campaign/:campaignId/settings',
                accept: presets.api + 'campaign/:campaignId/acceptContractTerms',
                list:   presets.api + 'campaign/:campaignId/helloSignTemplates',
                create: presets.api + 'campaign/:campaignId/helloSignTemplates/create',
                post:   presets.api + 'campaign/:campaignId/helloSignTemplates',
                patch:  presets.api + 'campaign/:campaignId/helloSignTemplates/:templateId',
                delete: presets.api + 'campaign/:campaignId/helloSignTemplates/:templateId',
```

I'd really like to **delete all text that is not inside single quotes**. What would the vim regex command for that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's arguably even easier to do this *without* regular expressions, by using the [`:normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) command. To delete the text on one line you would type: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, which deletes to the first quote (`df'`), moves to the next quote (`;`), and then deletes the rest of the line (`D`). So to do this on the entire file with one command, run:

```
:%norm!df';D
```

If you wanted to keep the quote marks as well, the command is slightly longer, but just as simple:

```
:%norm!dt';llD
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's given that only one single-quoted text will appear in a line, then the regex is simple:

```
%s:\v.{-}('.{-}').*:\1:
```

- `%s`: run `:h :substitute` over the whole buffer
- `:`: delimiter
- `\v`: use `:h /magic` mode
- pattern to be replaced

  - `.{-}`: select least-possible characters
  - `'(.{-})'`: select text wrapped in single-quotes and mark it as sub-expression (see `:h /\(`)
  - `.*`: match any text as many number of times as possible
- `:`: delimiter
- `\1`: replace the matched pattern with the first sub-expression (which is the text wrapped in single-quotes.

---

This will leave only the first single-quoted text and delete everything else. If two or more single-quoted text exist in a line, this regex will not be functional. We can devise another regex for that case, but since that is slightly more difficult to come up with, I'm leaving it as to-be-done only if the OP expresses they require it.